# New-PSDrive works interactively but not in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, cruisecontrol.net

I am attempting to use a New-PSDrive to mount a share and then read items from it.

```
function NRLFind ([object[]]$Releases) {
    $relvols = @{}

    New-PSDrive -Name NRL -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\FileServer\shareName" 
    foreach ($dir in $(Get-Item NRL:\* | where {$_.PsIsContainer})) {
        foreach($release in $Releases) {
            if ($d = get-item $($dir.FullName + '\' + $release.glob) -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue) { 
              if(! $relvols[$release.name] -or $relvols[$release.name].LastWriteTime -lt $d.LastWriteTime) {
                $relvols[$release.name] = $d
              }
            }
        }
    }
    $relvols
}
```

It's bombing on the New-PSDrive line, with the error: New-PSDrive : Drive root "\FileServer\shareName" does not exist or it's not a folder.

The interesting part is that the New-PSDrive command works when run interactively, but not in the PS script.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've found another piece to the puzzle.  I'm using this PS Script in our CruiseControl.net CI server process.  The PS Script works when run from the command line, but not when run as the server process.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user who runs the script has permissions to access the share.